# Using try-finally to execute statements after return

Tags: java, performance, try-finally

Consider the following code:

```
Foo result = array[index];
index = (index + 1) % array.length;
return result;
```

In order to perform some final actions an extra variable is required. Does it make sense to write it as:

```
try {
    return array[index];
} finally {
    index = (index + 1) % array.length;
}
```

or will it have an impact on performance? It is, in general, considered a good/bad practice, and if so, why?

(In the example it is assumed that `index` is a valid index for `array` and the code will not throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`)

Edit: the question is not about the need to use `try-finally` but rather about any gain or loss in performance I get by choosing to do it. Without it, a variable is created. With it, the returned value is stored somewhere else, perhaps in a more efficient way.

Comment: Have you tried ?

Comment: If it will never throw an exception, you don't need `try/finally`. `finally` is to ensure that the code executes after `try`ing regardless of whether exception occurs or not.

Comment: I am afraid that the results of a purely empirical test may not be reliable, as this seems like something that may depend on the JVM being used or other details. As I would like to hear a more general answer that goes beyond specific cases I think it makes sense to see what someone with experience in the field will say.

Comment: Apart from any noticeable performance effect, I would argue that it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: The biggest impact is using `%` rather than using a mask e.g. `&` or a condition. https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2011/02/efficient-c-tip-13-use-the-modulus-operator-with-caution/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `finally` you declare indeed an additional `Foo` variable.
But is it really expensive ? Not as in both cases the `Foo` object exists in memory. You just added a reference to access to it.
A reference to an object in the scope of a method is really cheap.
You should never worry about that.

Besides, you don't have to use `finally` statement as a way to improve the performance of the executed code.
Readers of the code will never guess such a thing.
`finally` serves to :

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This
>   ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected
>   exception occurs.

and

> putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice,
>   even when no exceptions are anticipated.

The first code without the `finally` statement is much clearer and doesn't have any reading indirection.

So I advise to stick to  :

```
Foo result = array[index];
index = (index + 1) % array.length;
return result;
```

Answer (score 5):

As commented the main overhead is the use of `%` instead of a condition or mask

You can run a benchmark with JMH

```
static class Foo {

}

Foo[] array = new Foo[8];
int index = 0;

@Benchmark
public Foo simple() {
    Foo result = array[index];
    index = (index + 1) % array.length;
    return result;
}

@Benchmark
public Foo withFinally() {
    try {
        return array[index];
    } finally {
        index = (index + 1) % array.length;
    }
}

@Benchmark
public Foo withCondition() {
    int i = index++;
    if (index == array.length) index = 0;
    return array[i];
}

@Benchmark
public Foo withMask() {
    int i = index++;
    return array[i & (array.length-1)];
}
```

Results on my machine ... Your Mileage *Will* Vary

```
Benchmark               Mode  Cnt    Score   Error   Units
ModMain.simple         thrpt   25  132.473 ± 1.764  ops/us
ModMain.withCondition  thrpt   25  363.077 ± 4.752  ops/us
ModMain.withFinally    thrpt   25  130.179 ± 1.585  ops/us
ModMain.withMask       thrpt   25  397.310 ± 3.506  ops/us
```

Higher is better.

In short, using `finally` might be slightly slower, but I wouldn't worry about it compared to the alternatives.